# Thinking outLoud Conditional if statement Vs. For statement

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, conditional-statements

I have been working with java for a little more than a year. I recently have built a tic tac tow game as an assignment for my java class. After instructor graded it, he wrote a comment around my validation method logic. Even though I got 100% he said that the logic in my validation method is too cumbersome. He stated that I look into a for statement or a while statement in order to clean out some code in my validation method. This is my question is there really a way to put all my conditional if statements in to a for loop or a while loop? And if so I would like to know what logic goes behind that. This program had a set of five arrays but in this validation method I worked only with the JButton array.

```
JButton button = new Jbutton[9];

public void validate()
    {
        if(button[0].getText().equals(button[1].getText()) && button[1].getText().equals(button[2].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[0].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[3].getText().equals(button[4].getText()) && button[4].getText().equals(button[5].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[3].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[6].getText().equals(button[7].getText()) && button[7].getText().equals(button[8].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[6].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[0].getText().equals(button[3].getText()) && button[3].getText().equals(button[6].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[0].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[1].getText().equals(button[4].getText()) && button[4].getText().equals(button[7].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[1].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[1].getText().equals(button[4].getText()) && button[4].getText().equals(button[7].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[1].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[2].getText().equals(button[5].getText()) && button[5].getText().equals(button[8].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[2].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[0].getText().equals(button[4].getText()) && button[4].getText().equals(button[8].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[0].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }
        else if(button[2].getText().equals(button[4].getText()) && button[4].getText().equals(button[6].getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you the winner is" + button[2].getText());
            gameOver();
            return;
        }

        int i;

        for(i=0;i<button.length;i++)
        {
            if(button[i].isEnabled())
            {
                break;
            }
        }


        if(i == button.length)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This was a Draw");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your first easy step towards cleanup would be extracting a method that says `return button[i].getText().equals(button[j].getText()) && button[j].getText().equals(button[k].getText());`

Comment: Ok Getting rid of that is the best approach you are right.  Should a make a for statement and if so, what how is it possible to fit so many conditions into one?

Comment: I always go step by step. Do the above, then extract the then-block into another method; then you'll have a compact series of else-ifs where just the numbers change. Then you may come up with something further.

Comment: Extract also the message and the `gameover` method. Then look if you have some pattern for i/j/k ... something like a progression ... progressions could be represented by loops (for, while).

Answer (score 0):

If there is a way to find the winner using a mathematical progression for the combination of the buttons, then you could probably extract the checks in a loop.

You could also refactor your code by extracting the repetative tasks, for example (as already suggested) doing this:

- extract the `if` condition for the buttons in a separate function
- extract the message in a separate function
- extract the return index in a separate function and call `gameOver()` and return only once

Your code would be then much readable and shorter:

```
    private Boolean checkConditionFor(int button1, int button2, int button3) {
        return button[button1].getText().equals(button[button2].getText()) 
            && button[button2].getText().equals(button[button3].getText());
    }

    private void messageFor(int id) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you the winner is" + button[id].getText());
        gameOver();
    }

    private int winner() {
        if(checkConditionFor(0, 1, 2) || 
           checkConditionFor(0, 3, 6) || 
           checkConditionFor(0, 4, 8)) { return 0; }
        if(checkConditionFor(3, 4, 5)) { return 3; }
        if(checkConditionFor(6, 7, 8)) { return 6; }
        if(checkConditionFor(1, 4, 7)) { return 1; }
        if(checkConditionFor(2, 5, 8) || 
           checkConditionFor(2, 4, 6)) { return 2; }
    }
```

Now just call the functions in the `validate` method:

```
    messageFor(winner());
    return;
```